# TextBox1 doesn't show the listbox1 value

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I'm Visual Basic beginner, yesterday i wrote a dictionary that give you the opposite of the entered word, so i designed the form to look like this

[url]http://img651.imageshack.us/img651/6115/errorbp.jpg[url]

by the way i made a two list boxes as databases so the code will compare if the textbox1.text = listbox1.text then it will command textbox2 to append the value of the listbox : textbox2.appendtext(listbox2.text) but nothing happens
my code:

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
End Sub
Private Sub TnsBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If TextBox1.Text = TextBox3.ToString Then
        TextBox2.AppendText(ListBox2.Text)

    ElseIf TextBox1.Text = TextBox4.Text Then
        TextBox2.AppendText(ListBox1.ToString)


    End If
End Sub

Private Sub AddBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox3.Text)
    ListBox2.Items.Add(TextBox4.Text)
End Sub
```

End Class
the point of the code is ok cuz yesterday i finished the coding and the programs works fine but i forget to save it so i coded again and every thing above happens
this is the yesterday program

http://www.mediafire.com/?tavne7xjyth7y7v
virustotal link:
https://www.virustotal.com/file/1d39429ae1498a744e1556188b7e8914526b7e2fbb2d4904c2b4ea22fb278dc7/analysis/1346676641/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially you are setting the textbox text to "ListBox" without choosing anything specific so it is calling ToString() on the listbox which is why you get that.

I would change the method so that you have a Dictionary variable like so:

```
  Public Sub Translate(input As String)
    TextBox2.Text = OppositeDictionaires(input)
  End Sub
  Public OppositeDictionary As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
  'Call as Add(TextBox3.Text, TextBox4.Text)
  Public Sub Add(input As String, opposite As String)
    OppositeDictionary.Add(input, opposite)
  End Sub
```

Call add from your event and then Translate from your translate event. You should then get your output as intended, still add them to the listboxes if you want to display to the user but handle the translation in the code behind through a dictionairy object.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx

Comment: Public Class Form1
   
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        
       
        If TextBox1.Text = TextBox5.Text Then
            TextBox2.AppendText(ListBox2.Text)
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        TextBox5.Text = TextBox3.Text
        TextBox6.Text = TextBox4.Text
        ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox3.Text)
        ListBox2.Items.Add(TextBox4.Text)
    End Sub" i just want know y its not working

Comment: I don't get how it would ever work? You have no way of mapping one listbox to the other. There has to be some sort of binding between them, at the minute your just adding values to a list box and then expecting them to magically come out together again?

Comment: dude i made a program works that way u can download it i linked it:http://www.mediafire.com/?tavne7xjyth7y7v                          virusscan:https://www.virustotal.com/file/1d39429ae1498a744e1556188b7e8914526b7e2fbb2d4904c2b4ea22fb278dc7/analysis/1346676641/                         but i forget to save my work then i got here

Comment: just click continue when the error appears      btw the list boxes are my database u see that i can't translate anything without adding a word to databases which are the list boxes

Comment: Don't get all stressy - the way your doing this is incorrect I am just trying to help you and better your code and give you an option to fix this as well as learn something. I also explained why this wasn't working, and you were seeing listbox2, count etc. in the textbox. You currently have NO WAY of mapping a value to another the translator value so the only way for me to answer this question is with an alternate approach. What happens if you change textbox3? By not doing my answer, your just delaying yourself and being pathetic.

Comment: thanx for every thing, but i tried that and changed it to textbox3 its now like depends on textbox3 so there is no databases it shows what is entered in textbox3, did u download the program i linked plz do to c if i'm correct

Comment: For a start - can you please sort out your naming conventions. Instead of "textbox1" because that is too ambiguous.

Comment: ok take a look at this link : http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?y0o0xds27zye290

Comment: go to my topic in MDSN http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/6fba171e-a3b1-419c-a681-d541766322d6